# How to close multiple dialog box using Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a running Angular 9 application and I have created custom dialog box. I have also used ComponentFactoryResolver to dynamically load the component.

My custom dialog box looks like:

[image]

So, when I click on close button, the dialog box closes.

As per the current implementation, if I open multiple dialog box on the screen, then I am able to close only last opened dialog box by clicking on close button.

My expected behavior is to close all the dialog box. Please help me on this

Stackblitz demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-box-overlay

Note: In this stackblitz demo, one modal opens on the top of another modal as I have not modified the css. So, please focus on Modal name to get to know which modal is opened

Comment: Look at the angular material dialog. You should return a dialogRef instance, which should also be injectable in your dialog. This dialogRef needs to do the 'close', not the dialogService. Or you can somehow create a map of dialogs inside the dialogService, and pass a parameter in your close method to determine which one to close

Comment: @PierreDuc can you please update the stackblitz code so that I can get clear idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the created modal component to the services `dcRef` property you need to manage all of your modal components, i.e. in a list. Your service's `open()` method

```
open(component: Type<any>, modalName: string) {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DialogComponent);
    this.dcRef = factory.create(this.injector);
    ...
    return this.dcRef;
}
```

returns the component reference. You could manage this reference from the caller and pass it as an argument to your `close()` method. When all of the component refs are managed by the service you can also "batch close" all modals (see `closeAll()`):

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogService {

    refs: ComponentRef<DialogComponent>[] = [];

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
        private injector: Injector
    ) { }

    open(component: Type<any>, modalName: string) {
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DialogComponent);
        var ref = factory.create(this.injector);
        this.applicationRef.attachView(ref.hostView);
        const domElement = (ref.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
        document.body.appendChild(domElement);
        ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        ref.instance.open(component, modalName);
        this.refs.push(ref);
        return ref;
    }

    close(ref) {        
        this.applicationRef.detachView(ref.hostView);
        ref.instance.close();
        ref.destroy();
        // Remove ref from a list managed by the service
        var i = this.refs.indexOf(ref);
        this.refs.splice(i, 1);
    }

    closeAll()
    {       
        this.refs.forEach(r => this.close(r));
    }
}
```

This is not tested and might need to be tuned, but you should get the idea. Instead of using the `ComponentRef` as a handle you can also create some custom object to prevent the caller of the modal to interact with the component directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marc. Can you please tell me what reference to pass in the parameter of close method. eg: If I am using ErrorModalComponent then should I pass     
  `ref: ComponentRef<ErrorModalComponent>; ` while calling close method of service like           `this.dialogServic.close(ref)`

Comment: @asif905 The idea is to pass the handle that you received as return value from the open() method: `var ref = service.open(...); service.close(ref);`